# What files do I need in /root?

Tags: debian-wheezy

I extracted a ton of files to /root on accident and they're all over. I want to delete all the files in there *except* for the ones I need. What ones are required to be in the /root file to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost everything that is in the /root folder by default came from `/etc/skel`  So you could probably safely **move** or remove your existing `/root`, create a new folder, then copy the contents of `/etc/skel` to `/root`.  Make sure you get the permissins right.

These commands would reset you to a state that is close to what you would see when the system was installed.

```
mv /root /root_broke
mkdir /root
rsync -va /etc/skel /root
chown -R root:root /root
```

Answer (score 1):

/root is the root users home directory. There's nothing in there of any importance by default. Now if your talking about / that is a different story.

Comment: So I can clean the entire directory? Won't that delete all the profile information (password etc)?

Comment: no, deleting the home directory for the user will not delete your login info. IIRC, next time the user logs in, the home dir is automatically recreated in a default state. in your case, you could rename /root to /root.bak, and then login as root to recreate the home based on the skeletons your distribution provided.

Comment: Your password is stored in `/etc/shadow`, and a couple settings (such as default shell) in `/etc/passwd`.  Group information is in `/etc/group` and `/etc/gshadow`.  As long as this info is there, you can log on, even if you blow away your home directory.